# Get tthe last word of a string that has whitespace

Tags: javascript

I have a string that follows the format `var string = "word1 word2 - word3"` (the `-` is just a dash that seperates words 2 & 3.

Is there a better way of extracting word3 from `string` other than `string.split(" ")[3]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple RegExp with a capturing group like this:

```js
const string1 = "word1 word2 - word3";
const string2 = "word1 word2 +&* word3";
const string3 = "word1+-*/)=word2 -           word3";

const regex = /\w+\W+\w+\W+(\w+)/;

const [, thirdWord1] = regex.exec(string1);
const [, thirdWord2] = regex.exec(string2);
const [, thirdWord3] = regex.exec(string3);

console.log(thirdWord1, thirdWord2, thirdWord3);
```

This solution is more tolerant to strings not matching exactly the pattern (e.g: more spaces, no dash, etc...). It always retrieves the third word.

Comment: We answered at the same time with the same idea.

Comment: Yes but different pattern, you are using the dash as landmark regardless of the number of words, while I'm using non-word characters and get the third word ; I guess it depends whether OP wants to validate that input strings have exactly three words or not.

Comment: is there a reson why using regex is better?

Comment: Yes but it depends on your needs, I've added a detail about it

Comment: @web-dev it can be more accurate and fit more situations (if you twist things around a bit).

Comment: @GuerricP could could you further explain the syntax [ , thirdWord1]? Never seen that before

Comment: This is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) just a short syntax to retrieve the second item of the array and give it a variable name. The first item of the array is actually the full match which is not useful in your case so I don't give any name to it, that's why the immediate comma. In short, this in equivalent of `const thirdWord1 = regex.exec(string1)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Regex would work:

```js
var string = "word1 word2 - word3";
var result = string.replace(/^.* \- /, "");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure there is a dash between "word2" and "word3", you can split the string using that dash character

```js
const string = "word1 word2 - word3";
const word3 = string.split(" - ")[1];
console.log(word3)
```